# share extension in ios 8 with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on share extension. i want to select my application and then need to show categories list. user can select category name and want to implement my webservices.

How to show category list and to do actions in ios ?

Thanks

Comment: Would you elaborate your case? How many categories are there? and what you want to share? and what type of service you want to request?

Comment: I want to share url and need to select category list... sevrice so that it save into databse